# Trouble getting 8-bit palette output working with SDL 2.0

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

Here's my code, using SDL 2.0.4 on OSX 10.11.4:

```
SDL_Surface *output_surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_Texture *output_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);

SDL_Color c[256];

// Setting each color to red as a test.
for(u8 i = 255; i--;) {
    c[i].r = 255;
    c[i].g = 0;
    c[i].b = 0;
}

SDL_SetPaletteColors(output_surface->format->palette, c, 0, 256);
```

Then later...

```
SDL_Rect r = {
    .x = 0,
    .y = 0,
    .w = width,
    .h = height
};

// Doesn't fill with red.
SDL_FillRect(output_surface, &r, 4);

SDL_UpdateTexture(output_texture, NULL, output_surface->pixels, output_surface->pitch);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, output_texture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

What I would expect to see is the full window all red but I'm getting something entirely different.  Changing the color number passed to `SDL_FillRect` shows that I'm getting a grayscale palette (0 is black, 255 is white) even though `SDL_SetPaletteColors` doesn't return an error and i've looped through `output_surface->format->palette->colors` to verify the palette's been changed.

What am I missing here?

edit: I was asked to post an entire program.  Here it is:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *output_surface = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *output_texture = NULL;

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) < 0) return 0;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Sample", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, 0);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    output_surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    output_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);

    SDL_Color c[256];

    for(u8 i = 255; i--;) {
        c[i].r = 255;
        c[i].g = 0;
        c[i].b = 0;
        c[i].a = 255;
    }

    SDL_SetPaletteColors(output_surface->format->palette, c, 0, 255);

    SDL_Rect r = {
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .w = width,
        .h = height
    };

    bool running = true;

    while(running) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_FillRect(output_surface, &r, 124);

        SDL_UpdateTexture(output_texture, NULL, output_surface->pixels, output_surface->pitch);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, output_texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(output_surface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(output_texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Passing `0` to `SDL_FillRect` is black, `255` is white, and any number in-between is a shade of grey.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the solution.

Remove this line:

```
output_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);
```

And instead add this line somewhere after the call to `SDL_SetPaletteColors` or after you change the surfaces' pixels (like in the game loop):

```
output_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, output_surface);
```